# how to make json of html files with php

Tags: php, json

I want to make php file which:

1. Take all html templates
2. put them to array
3. make json from array

Now i had some of this:

```
$dirpath = "../templates/popups/";
$dh = opendir($dirpath);
$popups = array();

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {

    if (!is_dir($file)) {

        $popups[substr($file,0,-5)] = 
            strip_tags(file_get_contents("../templates/popups/".$file));


    }

}

closedir($dh);

$popups = array_map('htmlentities',$popups);
$screens = array_map('htmlentities',$screens);

echo "tmpPopups = JSON.parse('".html_entity_decode(
    json_encode($popups, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT))."'
);";
```

Comment: ... and? What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you have, what do you need, what error you get? Just a "I want that" is not a question.

Comment: When i load this file as js i had unexpected token when json is parsing. propably it's problem when html file is compressing to json. Have you any ideas to fixed it? 

This is my solution for error 412 when sometimes when i try load html files by ajax. I want to have all templates in json and don't use ajax to load html files.